# Unable to fix Multiple dex files compilation issue

Tags: android

I need to use `androidsupportv4.jar` for some features and `android-support-v13.jar`for app navigation drawer functions, but unfortunately this cause the error:

```
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter;
```

I don't know how to fix this because if I remove `androidsupportv4.jar`or `android-support-v13.jar` get a lot of other errors because many function of the Holo GUI of my app use these libraries.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android-support-v13` contains all classes of `android-support-v4` and in addition other features,
you can simply remove `android-support-v4` and use only `android-support-v13`to avoid collisions.

Pay attention to clean your project and if the bin folder contains `android-support-v4.jar` remove it and rebuild the App before try again.